# Data binding attributes of dynamically created polymer elements

Tags: javascript, polymer

If I want to bind the attributes of two polymer elements together then I can use data binding in a template and do the following:

```
<!-- Publish .items so others can use it for attribute binding. -->
<polymer-element name="td-model" attributes="items">
  <script>
    Polymer('td-model', {
      ready: function() {
        this.items = [1, 2, 3];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="my-app">
  <template>
    <td-model items="{{list}}"></td-model>
    <polymer-localstorage name="myapplist" value="{{list}}"></polymer-localstorage>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-app', {
      ready: function() {
        // Initialize the instance's "list" property to empty array.
        this.list = this.list || [];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

> From http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/communication.html#binding

However, if I'm creating an element (let's call it) `<my-childelement>` dynamically using `document.createElement()` inside of another element `<my-parentelement>` then how can I synchronise changes made to an attribute of my-childelement with my-parent element?

One option is to emit events from the child element and subscribe to them in the parent, but this is tedious when I have quite a lot of attributes that I want to keep in sync and I then have to manage adding/removing listeners whenever the childelement is replaced with a different child element.

[Node.bind()](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/node_bind.html) looks like it might be after but I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding it's purpose.

I'm hoping to be able to do something along the lines of this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-parentelement" attributes="shape">
  <script>
    Polymer('my-parentelement', {
      shape: square,
      ready: function() {
        var child = document.createElement('my-childelement');
        this.bind('shape', new PathObserver(child, 'shape');

        // Now this.shape will be kept in sync with child.shape, e.g.
        child.shape = 'triangle';
        this.shape == child.shape; // evaluates to true
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: I realize it's generally annoying when people don't answer your question directly, but managing elements is much easier with `<template>` and in particular all the fancy data-binding machinery is declarative. IOW, I'd rather help you avoid `createElement` than provide incantations to do imperative binding. Are you willing to describe your core problem more fully?

Comment: Sure thing! I'm creating a bunch of elements that provide a unified API to embedding players for various media sites, such as YouTube, SoundCloud, and Vimeo. I'm then creating a generic `player` element which has a `source` attribute which can be set to a URL (`http://www.youtu.be/v/VMVj_jR75vE`, or `https://soundcloud.com/thump/mesck-conquista`, etc.) and it will internally use the correct sub-element and bind the sub-elements API to it's own API. Let me know if a gist with pseudocode would make things clearer!

Answer (score 4):

There are various ways one can handle this kind of polymorphism, but in this case, it seems like simple template conditionals are a good fit. IOW, something like this

```
  <template>
    <template if="{{kind == 'vimeo'}}">
      Vimeo: {{name}}
    </template>
    <template if="{{kind == 'soundcloud'}}">
      Soundcloud <b>{{name}}</b>
    </template>
    ...
```

Running version here: http://codepen.io/sjmiles/pen/FkacJ?editors=100

Comment: Thanks, that's not a bad idea. However, I'm not a big fan of the amount of duplication that will be involved as there will be an increasing number of elements, each with around 10 identical attributes to bind to.

Comment: Duplication of what? You mean `<v-element ...>`, `<t-element ...>`, etc. where `...` is the same each time?

Comment: Yep, not a massive issue though!

Answer (score 3):

This works for me to dynamically add a custom element and then bind it.  I also have an example of dynamically importing the element, then loading and then binding it.

Runnable code here: https://github.com/semateos/polymer-lazy-load

demo-app.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="lazy-test.html">

<polymer-element name="demo-app" attributes="session">
  <template>

    <input type="text" value="{{session.id}}">

    <button on-tap="{{buttonClick}}">Test</button>

    <div id="holder"></div>

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      buttonClick: function(e){

        //create the polymer element
        var child = document.createElement('lazy-test');

        //bind the session value to the parent
        child.bind('session', new PathObserver(this, 'session'));

        //attach it to the parent
        this.$.holder.appendChild(child);
      },

      created: function() {

        //set the initial value
        this.session = {id: '123'};
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

lazy-test.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="lazy-test" attributes="session">
  <template>

    <h1>Lazy Child: {{session.id}}</h1>

    <input type="text" value="{{session.id}}">

  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({

      created: function() {

        // hint that session is an object
        this.session = {};
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```